# Zip Multiple file Than unlink the file

Tags: php, file, zip, unlink

```
    <?php



$direc = base64_decode($_GET['path']);



    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }
    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach ($file_names as $files) {
        $zip->addFile($file_path . $files, $files);
    }
    $zip->close();



    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $archive_file_name);
    header('Cache-control: private, must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
    $file_names = $_POST['file'];
    $archive_file_name = 'zipped.zip';
    $file_path = $direc;
    echo $file_path;


//Run Function above
    zipFilesAndDownload($file_names, $archive_file_name, $file_path);


    if (file_exists($archive_file_name)) {
        unlink($archive_file_name);
    }

?>
```

I find code above and try it, The zip file created but statement `unlink($zipname);` doesn't work
**I don't have any problem about permission**

Is that file strill write-protected?
How to solve that problem?

Thanks Friends

Comment: where do you set `$zipname` and `$zipfilename`?

Comment: Sorry wrong code copied..I've corrected it :D..Is the problem is the `unlink` statement below the header statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function above should call return, not exit. Exit terminates execution of the script, so nothing after that will be called. It's probably not even getting to the file_exists part.